# Remove duplicate records from mongodb 4.0

Tags: mongodb

i have a collection which has duplicate records. I am using mongodb 4.0. How do i remove the duplicate records from the entire collection?

the record are getting inserted with the following structure
{ item: "journal", qty: 25, size:15 , status: "A" }

All i need is to have unique records for one document.

Answer (score 2):

You can group duplicated records using aggregation pipeline:

```
db.theCollection.aggregate([
   {$group: {_id: {item: "$item", qty: "$qty", size: "$size", status: "$status"}}},
   {$project: {_id: 0, item: "$_id.item", qty: "$_id.qty", size: "$_id.size", status: "$_id.status"}},
   {$out: "theCollectionWithoutDuplicates"}
])
```

After the execution of aggregation pipeline, the `theCollectionWithoutDuplicates` collection contains a document for each group of original duplicated documents, with a new `_id` - you can verify the output, removing original collection (`db.theCollection.drop()`) and rename the new collection (`db.theCollectionWithoutDuplicates.renameCollection('theCollection')`). Drop and rename can be combined in `db.theCollectionWithoutDuplicates.renameCollection('theCollection', true)`.

EXPLANATION of aggregation pipeline usage:

1. `db.theCollection.aggregate([])` executes an aggregation pipeline, receiving a list of aggregation stages to be executed
2. the `$group` stage groups document by fields specified as subsequent `_id` field
3. the `$project` stage changes field names, flattening nested `_id` subdocuments produced by `$group`
4. the `$out` stage stores aggregation resulting documents into given collection

Comment: Thanks Pietro, actually i am fetching the data from a source on a daily basis,and the data have duplicate records,i want to avoid the duplicate insertion and moreover remove the older  existing duplicates without changing the collection name

Comment: You can avoid duplicated data insertion defining an (unique) index on the collection: `db.theCollection.createIndex({ "item": 1, "qty": 1, "size": 1, "status": 1 }, { unique: true })`. May be you can use my approach to obtain a collection without duplicates and then create the unique index to preserve record unicity fot the future... alternatively, if you don't want to use a second, temporary collection, dropping the old and renaiming it, you can use the original collection name (`theCollection` on my example) as value for `$out` pipeline stage ({$out: "theCollection"})...

Answer (score 2):

You can remove duplicated records using forEach:

```
db.collection.find({}, { item: 1, qty: 1, size: 1, status: 1 }).forEach(function(doc) {
    db.collection.remove({_id: { $gt: doc._id }, item: doc.item, qty: doc.qty, size: doc.size, status: doc.status })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently create a code to delete duplicated documents from MongoDB, this should work:

```
const query = [
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        field: "$field",
      },
      dups: {
        $addToSet: "$_id",
      },
      count: {
        $sum: 1,
      },
    },
  },
  {
    $match: {
      count: {
      $gt: 1,
      },
    },
  },
];

const cursor = collection.aggregate(query).cursor({ batchSize: 10 }).exec();

cursor.eachAsync((doc, i) => {
  doc.dups.shift(); // First element skipped for deleting
  doc.dups.map(async (dupId) => {
    await collection.findByIdAndDelete({ _id: dupId });
  });
});
```