# Mongodb: Deduplicate collection

Tags: mongodb

I'm working with mongo and node. I have a collection with a large number of records an unknown number of which are duplicates. I'm trying to remove dups following [Remove duplicate records from mongodb 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54517837/remove-duplicate-records-from-mongodb-4-0) and https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/ .

I am using the mongodb compass tool. I am able to run the code in the mongodb Shell at the bottom of this tool.

So far I have:

```
db.hayes.aggregate([
...     {"$group" : {_id:"$PropertyId", count:{$sum:1}}}
... ]
... );
{ "_id" : "R135418", "count" : 10 }
{ "_id" : "R47410", "count" : 17 }
{ "_id" : "R130794", "count" : 10 }
{ "_id" : "R92923", "count" : 18 }
{ "_id" : "R107811", "count" : 11 }
{ "_id" : "R91389", "count" : 15 }
{ "_id" : "R22047", "count" : 12 }
{ "_id" : "R103664", "count" : 10 }
{ "_id" : "R121349", "count" : 12 }
{ "_id" : "R143168", "count" : 8 }
{ "_id" : "R85918", "count" : 13 }
{ "_id" : "R41641", "count" : 13 }
{ "_id" : "R160910", "count" : 11 }
{ "_id" : "R48919", "count" : 11 }
{ "_id" : "M119387", "count" : 10 }
{ "_id" : "R161734", "count" : 12 }
{ "_id" : "R41259", "count" : 13 }
{ "_id" : "R156538", "count" : 7 }
{ "_id" : "R60868", "count" : 10 }
```

How do I now select 1 of each of the groups to avoid duplicates . (I can see that loading it into a new collection will likely involve:    {$out: "theCollectionWithoutDuplicates"}
)

edit:

The output from db.hayes.aggregate([
{
$group: {
_id: "$PropertyId",
count: {
$sum: 1
},
ids: {
$addToSet: "$_id"
}
}
},
{
$match: {
count: {
$gt: 1
}
}
}
]) gives output looking like:

```
{ "_id" : "M118975", "count" : 8, "ids" : [ ObjectId("60147f84e9fdd41da73272d6"), ObjectId("601427ac432deb152a70b8fd"), ObjectId("6014639be210571a70d1118f"), ObjectId("60145e9ae210571a70d0062f"), ObjectId("60145545b6f7a917817e9519"), ObjectId("6014619be210571a70d0a091"), ObjectId("60145dc3d5a2811a459b4e07"), ObjectId("60146641e210571a70d1a3cd") ] }
{ "_id" : "R88986", "count" : 10, "ids" : [ ObjectId("60131752de3d3a09bc1eb04b"), ObjectId("6013348385dcda0eb5b8d40c"), ObjectId("60145297b6f7a917817e1928"), ObjectId("601458eeb08c4919df85f63d"), ObjectId("601462f4e210571a70d0e961"), ObjectId("60142ad9c0db1716068a612e"), ObjectId("601425263df18a145b2fd0a8"), ObjectId("60145be5d5a2811a459aea7e"), ObjectId("6014634ce210571a70d0fe5c"), ObjectId("60131a1ab7335806a1816b95") ] }
{ "_id" : "P119977", "count" : 11, "ids" : [ ObjectId("601468b9597abd1bfd0798a4"), ObjectId("60144b7dbfa28016887b0e8f"), ObjectId("60147094c4bca31cfdb12d1d"), ObjectId("60144de7bfa28016887b698b"), ObjectId("60135aa63674d90dffec3759"), ObjectId("60135f552441920e97e858a3"), ObjectId("601428b3432deb152a70f32e"), ObjectId("60141b222ac11f13055725a5"), ObjectId("60145326b6f7a917817e38b6"), ObjectId("6014882c5322582035e83f63"), ObjectId("6014741ae9fdd41da7313a44") ] }
```

However when I run the foreach loop it runs for minutes and crashes

Originally the database mydb had 0.173 GB but now 0.368 GB

any idea what is wrong?

edit 2:

I rebooted, then reran your entire script. this time it completed in a 3-4 minutes. No errors.

```
> show dbs
admin          0.000GB
config         0.000GB
local          0.000GB
myNewDatabase  0.000GB
mydb           0.396GB
> db.hayes.aggregate([ {"$group" : {_id:"$PropertyId", count:{$sum:1}}},{$count:"total"} ]);

{ "total" : 103296 }
> db.hayes.aggregate([ {"$group" : {_id:"$PropertyId", count:{$sum:1}}} ]);
{ "_id" : "R96274", "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "R106186", "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "R169417", "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "R140542", "count" : 1 }
```

So it looks like it worked this time, but why is 'mydb' getting larger?

Comment: There is a $first operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to keep single document from every duplicated list and remove the rest:

```
db.test.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$PropertyId",
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      },
      ids: {
        $addToSet: "$_id"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      count: {
        $gt: 1
      }
    }
  }
]).forEach(function(d){
  d.ids.shift();
  printjson(d.ids);
  db.test.remove({
    _id: {
      $in: d.ids
    }
  })
})
```

Explained:

1. You group by PropertyId and preserve every document _id in ids array
2. You filter only groups that have more then 1 document ( the duplicates )
3. You loop over all groups and remove 1st _id from ids array (the group for deletion)  and remove the duplicates.
   You can execute multiple times , if there is no duplicates no deletion will be executed ...

Comment: Thank you, but I'm running into a problem. Please see edit ..

Comment: any error messages when it craches? also is the size of the db increasing  or the oplog?

Comment: Please see my second edit - I think it worked? The total count of  103296 now appears to be the same as the number of groups, but why did the db get larger?